# Manjaro - How to add Korean keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, manjaro, locale, input, language

I've looked around multiple guides for Manjaro KDE to add a Korean keyboard, but none of them work. I can "swap" to Korean, but my input is still English. I've added Korean to my locale, installed the fonts, tried the guides for other languages, but nothing works. How can I install the Korean keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Since input is always changing, I wrote [Linuxreviews.org](https://linuxreviews.org/Category:Korean_Input_HOWTOs) guides for Korean input. If it ever changes, or if you're not using KDE, it will also be able to help you out.

1. Update your computer:

   ```
   sudo pacman -Syyu
   ```
2. Install `fcitx` and the Korean fonts:

   ```
   sudo pacman -S adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts fcitx-hangul kcm-fcitx
   ```
3. Add Korean to your system locale:

   ```
   sudo bash -c "echo ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen"
   ```
4. Restart your computer
5. Right click `fcitx` in your system tray (bottom right), select *Configure*
6. Deselect *Only show current language* (bottom left of `fcitx` configure window)
7. Search for *Hangul* in the languages, select it, and click the `>` icon to send it to *Current Input Method*
8. Hit *OK*

To type in Korean, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Here's a [video](https://odysee.com/@LinuxReviewsKr:9/ManjaroKDE-2021-Korean-Keyboard-Installation) as well.

Answer (score 2):

for fcitx5,

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
sudo pacman -S adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts fcitx5-hangul
```

and check `~/.config/fcitx5/profile`

```
# Group Name
Name="Group 1"
# Layout
Default Layout=us
# Default Input Method
DefaultIM=keyboard-us

[Groups/0/Items/0]
# Name
Name=hangul
# Layout
Layout=kr-kr104

[Groups/0/Items/1]
# Name
Name=keyboard-us
# Layout
Layout=

[GroupOrder]
0="Group 1"
```